# Attach public ip address to an AWS EC2 instance having multiple interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance having 3 interfaces attached to it.
I want to attach a public IP address for management but it looks like AWS does not allow auto-assign public IP address and asks to attach an elastic IP address.

Is there any way to add **an auto-assign** public IP address to an EC2 instance having multiple interfaces for instance management (not elastic ip)?

Comment: I want one public ip address for primary interface not for other interfaces

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it myself and, after adding multiple Elastic Network Interfaces, it displayed this message:

> **We can no longer assign a public IP address to your instance**
>
> The auto-assign public IP address feature for this instance is disabled because you specified multiple network interfaces. Public IPs can only be assigned to instances with one network interface. To re-enable the auto-assign public IP address feature, please specify only the eth0 network interface.

[image: EC2 instance with multiple ENIs]

Comment: yes, I get the same message. since elastic ips are limited I wanted to use auto-assign public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Please bring all your instance interfaces commonly to a VPCs public subnet which is resolving to the Public IP.

Hope this helps.